# Enable highlighting on selected words in all panes in SublimeText 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, highlight

If I select a word in one pane, this word doesn't highlight in other.

[image]

[image]

How can I make highlighting in both panes?

Comment: It is not what you are asking for but have you considered if `Find -> Find in Files...` might meet your needs via a different path? Every chance it won't but just in case you weren't aware it existed.

Comment: @jwpfox Thanks, I know about this feature. But it isn't what I need. I want this feature because of my work on many code files on different programming languages with same variable and constant names. And it might be useful to see all places, where I need to correct something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using ST out of the box. 
BUT, I'm pretty sure using the SublimeText Plugin API you can write a custom plugin to achieve this.
Have not seen any plugin that can do this till now.